# Thunderbird Lightning: Show only the future days

Tags: thunderbird, calendar, lightning

I just want to see the next days in thunderbird/lightning.

I could not find a configuration option to show the calendar with only the next days ahead.

I made a big red cross over the days I don't care about. Instead I want to see more days ahead.

[image: lightning-thunderbird-crossed-out-past]

Is there a way to get to this goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That *Week View* is displaying Calendar start from Start of the Week day that you can manually change/configure that for Thunderbird/Lightning Calendar from the following configuration path. But to keeping Today's day at first you should do this everyday!!

**Edit** menu --> **Preferences**; under **Calendar** tab click **Views**; then change the "*Start the week on:*" to today's week day!!

But below is a workaround with `sed` command which it does the same "Change ***Start the week on:***" for today's week day.

```bsh
sed -n -e '/^user_pref(\"calendar.week.start\", .);/!p' \
       -e "$ a\user_pref(\"calendar.week.start\", $(date +%u));" \
-i /home/$USER/.thunderbird/????????.default/prefs.js
```

Now [you can add this script into the Thunderbird's .desktop file to execute it every time you launch Thunderbird](/q/436891) in below path.

```
/usr/share/applications/thunderbird.desktop
```

Or you can simply run it via [crontab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) everyday at 00:00AM to change it to today's week day! Open to edit with `crontab -e` in Terminal.

```
0 0 * * * sed ...
```

Since this changes *Start the week day* to **Today's Day** every-time, so in Calendar it will show the Week start from Today.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Is there no easier way?

Comment: I don't think so there will be an easy way other than in my answer using crontab except you can ask Lightning team to add an option to ability to set Start the week day to today's day or something like that :  )